# Duda con reales y diccionarios en Python

Tags: python

Veréis, estoy en Codecademy haciendo este ejercicio: 
https://www.codecademy.com/es/courses/python-beginner-es-xxvnq/2/5?curriculum_id=53a32847fed2a88075000001#

Y no se me ocurre ningún modo de agregar 50 al valor 'oro'.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
inventario = {
'oro' : 500,
'morral' : ['piedra', 'soga', 'piedra preciosa'],
'mochila' : ['xilofon','cuchillo', 'bolsa de dormir','pan flauta'],
'bolsillo' : ['caracol', 'mora', 'lanas']
}

inventario['bolsa de arpillera'] = ['manzana', 'rubi chiquito', 'osito panda']

inventario['morral'].sort() 

# Aca va tu codigo
inventario['mochila'].sort()
inventario['mochila'].remove('cuchillo')
inventario['oro'].append(+50)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que debes tomar en cuenta es que el valor de la clave `oro` **no** es una lista, si no un entero, y consecuentemente no puedes utilizar el método `append`, es más, el método `append` en una lista no sirve para modificar/aumentar el valor numérico de sus elementos, si no que agrega un elemento a esta.

Luego, debes considerar que para modificar una variable tipo entero tienes que hacer una reasignación, por ejemplo:

```
a = 10 # Valor inicial de a
# ...
a = a + 5 # Aumentando el valor de a en 5
```

Lo mismo sucedería para el caso de tu diccionario:

```
inventario['oro'] = inventario['oro'] + 50
```

O si quieres *acortar* un poco:

```
inventario['oro'] += 50
```

Ya dependerá de cuál forma se te hace más *legible*.